# jQuery Dialog - Dialog with DataTables is not positioned centered

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, datatables, jquery-dialog

I got a jquery modal dialog which i load a jquery datatable inside. I cant make the dialog to display at the center (currently it keeps to the right)
Any idea what will be the possible cause & solution?
I tried position: center, but it dint work.
My script is like this:

```
    // Dialog for food details
    var $detaildialog;
    $detaildialog = $('#detaildialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Food Details',
        modal: true,
        position: 'center',
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto'

    });

     //Call Details action to display the food details
        var url = '/Food/Details?cid=' + id;

        //Use .load callback function to ensure details is loaded before dialog open
        $detaildialog.load(url, function () {
            $('#loading').hide();
            $detaildialog.dialog('open');
        });
```

And just showing part of my datatable html here:

```
<div id="tableplaceholder">
<table id="stocktable" class="pretty">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Amount
```

And css:

```
#tableplaceholder
 {
     width: 100%;
 }
```

Need help here... Appreciate any feedback......

Comment: Got a link where we can see the problem?

Comment: No... how can i do that?

Comment: Either link to the site, or recreate the problem on http://jsfiddle.net/ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although I not sure why, but after I fixed the dialog div width, the dialog is centered. Just post it here in case anyone having the same situation. Thanks!